# Mathpix - Image Retrieve

Tags: python, math

I have an jpg file which contains text and image, when I use mathpix, it only retrieves the text part.

Can you please help me how to retrieve both text and figures in my image ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using python as language

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code and an example of your file?